# javascript validation works for one value only

Tags: javascript, validation, alert

I am trying to validate two input fields in my form using javascript. But my functions checks only one value for `null` or `empty` string. It submits the form if the other value is empty. Why?

```
function checkFieldEmpty()
{
var a=document.forms["verifyURN"]["urnNumber"].value;
var b=document.forms["verifyURN"]["urnDate"].value;
if (a==null || a=="", b==null || b=="") //b field validates here, not a..?
{       
return false;
}
return true;  //function returns true even if a is empty..?
}

//Below function is called when submit button pressed in my form
function verifyURN()
{       
if(checkFieldEmpty())
{       
    document.verifyURN.rDoAction.value = "<%=Constant.myPage%>";
    document.verifyURN.submit();
}
else{
alert("Mandatory fields empty");
return false;
}       
}


...
<form name="verifyURN"...
```

Answer (score 0):

try add

```
alert(a.length);
alert(b.length);
```

before your

```
if (a==null || a=="", b==null || b=="") //b field validates here, not a..?
{
```

and you will have a better picture of what criteria to check.